# VCL TDBEdit Font->Charset Property not working as expected (C++ Builder 6) in 10.3

Tags: unicode, c++builder, vcl, ansi, codepages

I used to work with the `TDBEdit` component in C++Builder 6 in a way that I was able get text transformed from codepage 1252 to 1250 when I switched the `Font->Charset` from 1 (`DEFAULT_CHARSET`) to 238 (`EASTEUROPE_CHARSET`).

Example: `Œ` => `Ś`

Now, with 10.3, the switching of the `Charset` has no effect.

Is this a bug in the `TDBEdit` component, or is it simply not working anymore with Unicode? Why is the property still available?

I tried to understand the reason by debugging, but I couldn't get through.
The only thing I recognized was the different byte representation:

C++Builder 6: `'Œ'` 140 (0xFFFFF8C)

10.3: `'Œ'` -116 (0x8C)

I am really interested in the cause of the problem/misunderstanding of using `TDBEdit` in 10.3.

Comment: `140 (0xFFFFF8C)` and `-116 (0x8C)` are the same binary number, you are just viewing different representations of them (signed vs unsigned).  Also, `140` is always `0x8C` whether signed or unsigned, but `-116` is `0x8C` as 8 bits and `0xFFFFFF8C` as sign-extended 32-bits.

Comment: "*is it simply not working anymore with Unicode?*" - basically, yes. I would expect the `TDBEdit` to retrieve the DB text as Unicode (or converted to Unicode) before the `Font` ever sees it during rendering, so setting the `Font->Charset` is not relevant, as long as you are setting the `Font->Name` to a Unicode-aware font. "*Why is the property still available?*"- backward compatibility of legacy code.

Comment: I see, good to know, thanks. If the control is still backward compatible, how am I able to use it the old way in 10.3? I tried to set the font to a non-unicode aware font like Comic Sans MS, but still, the Œ character is displayed. Is there a chance to make it work again, to display the Ś? The same issue does occur in an TEdit control. I did even set Application->DefaultFont->Name to "Comic Sans MS", but it didn't work as expected. I would appreciate a workaround.

Comment: why do you need this in the first place? `Œ` is not `Ś`. Under ANSI, the `Charset` is simply telling the font to *reinterpret* the raw bytes it is given. But Unicode is not raw bytes. So if you want to display `Ś`, you need to start with `Ś` to begin with. For instance, by taking the Unicode text, encoding it to bytes using CP1252 bytes, decoding those bytes back to Unicode using CP1250, and then assigning the resulting Unicode to the Edit.

Comment: This is a bit tricky and I do depend on a database with the value stored with `Œ` (codepage 1252) in column A and the desired destination codepage (1250) is stored in column B. So the old TDBEdit was excellent for fulfilling this kind of codepage transformation (both equal 0x8C). I was able to display the `Ś` in the TDBEdit field by RawByte and SetCodepage code, but while entering the edit field, the text gets updated by its data field value with `Œ`. If I try to edit the value the `Ś` gets stored as a `S`, while in the bcb6 version it got stored as `Œ`. I am stuck.

Comment: I really don't understand what you are trying to accomplish, but it sounds like `TDBEdit` is not going to be a good solution for it anymore. You may have to switch to `TEdit` and handle the text and database separately. Or else write a custom data-aware Edit control that does what you need.

Comment: Sorry, if I couldn't point out the rationale. I try to display sql server varchar values (codepage 1252) in the TDBEdit field in a destination codepage (e.g. 1250- the value ist stored in another table column). When the user enters the TDBEdit field, the value is displayed in the destination codepage (1250). Editing the value and leaving the TDBEdit, the value gets stored in the table again with the original codepage (1252) due to the dataset binding. Could I transform the text to 1250 OnEnter, and retransform to 1252 OnExit? I need to set the Edit mode twice then, right?

Comment: I don't have a good solution for you other than what I've already described. Maybe you can set the DB column's charset to CP1252 and the DB connection's charset to CP1250, and it will just magically work? I don't know. This setup you want is very unusual, and not how Unicode environments are meant to work.

Comment: Nonetheless, thanks for your suggestions and ideas, I have to give it a try. Sometimes one needs to find unconventional solutions in the world of legacy code.